# Connect to mysql database on Ubuntu host from windows guest

Tags: networking, windows-7, mysql, vmware, firewall

I have Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and have a Windows 7 guest on (VMWare). I would like to connect to the mysql database on Ubuntu host from Windows guest.Kindly tell me how to do the same. I have tried the ODBC test connection but no success.

My current state is as below

1. I am able to SSH to the host IP address (given against the vmnet1 - output of `ifconfig` command on Ubuntu) and `ping` from Windows to Ubuntu host by giving Ubuntu machine name.
2. I understand that I need to comment the bind-address parameter in my.cnf and I did the same.

Now my question:

Now, I need to execute a statement in mysql server something similar to 
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO `username@address` IDENTIFIED BY `password`;

I am not sure what should be the value for the `address` as DHCP enabled on my guest (not sure what IP to give if I need to change this to a fixed IP)

Apart from this I also would like to know what is the approach for setting up a firewall for mysql server (as commented the bind-address) any gui tools for this with out causing any additional problems?

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky part.  With MySQL database, to access the database, MySQL screens, not only user and password, but host too.  Therefore, you need to identify this user with ip address in which this user will be connecting to MySQL from.